# PHP <b>Warning</b>: Illegal string offset 'image_name' from Android

Tags: php, android

Trying to send ***arraylist data to server using php*** as bridge from ***Android (using Volley)***, and successfully ***getting data into database table*** (and also ***getting response as submit***, I mentioned in ***php***) in Android

So everything ***looks perfect***, if we talk about **db connection, storage and response**, but one unusal issue ***always getting 2 in table field, instead the original value***

```
::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:11.jpg"}
::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:21.jpg"}
::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:31.jpg"}

::::Response::::: <br />

<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'image_name' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\send_data.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
    <br />
submit
```

Here is the ***foreach***, I'm using in ***php*** to ***upload all the data*** available in a ***list***

```
$content = $_POST['my_images'];

$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $image_name = $value["image_name"];
}
```

***android*** code

```
        ImageData imageData = new ImageData();
        imageData.setImageName(array[0]);

        String imageDataInString = new Gson().toJson(imageData);
        Log.d("::::imageDataInString::::", imageDataInString);

        ....
        params.put("my_images", imageDataInString);
```

in my ***csv***, available in ***raw*** folder of ***res*** in ***Android***, I have these ***data***:

```
2020-01-01_00:01:11.jpg
2020-01-01_00:01:21.jpg
2020-01-01_00:01:31.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. Can you please elaborate regarding what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: as you can see, I have image names in json object, I'm not getting these data (instead getting 2 as value for all those 3), like I'm trying to get 2020-01-01_00:01:11.jpg (but getting 2),  trying to get 2020-01-01_00:01:21.jpg (but getting 2) and trying to get 2020-01-01_00:01:31.jpg (but getting 2)... so my question is why I'm getting 2 always instead the actual data, I have in csv and json @AtishAgrawal

Comment: The error message means that `$value` is a _string_, so trying to access `$value["image_name"]` does not make sense. What does your `$json` actually look like? Show a var_dump, please.

Comment: I already posted above, whatever I'm getting as json object, when I fetch data from csv file and convert it to json... ::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:11.jpg"}
::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:21.jpg"}
::::imageDataInString::::: {"b":"2020-01-01_00:01:31.jpg"} @04FS

Comment: You were asked an explicit question, so please answer it, instead of giving us something else. Again: Show a var_dump of what your $json variable actually contains.

Comment: Show us the JSON

Comment: how do I print that? I'm Android developer don't know much about PHP... but still trying to collect things from web and doing experiment to get succeed

Comment: something like this: var_dump($json);

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to note:

GSON converts the variable names of the class (ImageData) as keys and appends the values, to form the JSON. Hence, you need to use the same variable names, as you have used in the ImageData class to fetch the data, in your PHP Code.

```
ImageData imageData = new ImageData();
imageData.setImageName(array[0]);
String imageDataInString = new Gson().toJson(imageData);
```

Hence, the array key should be `array["ImageName"]`

In your PHP code, the second line, where you are JSON decoding the `$content` variable, the variable `$json` is already converted in an `Array`. You don't need to iterate and fetch corresponding keys.

Hence, you should do something like this:

```
$content = $_POST['my_images'];    
$json = json_decode($content, true);    
$image_name = $json["ImageName"];
```

With this, the variable `$image_name` will hold the value which you are looking for.

Comment: Whenever, I'm accepting this answer, it says we won't display as you scored less than 15, but will keep in our records, in short to upvote this, I need atleast 15 points, those I don't have.. so everyone else has more than 15, I request you all please upvote this, as it solved my problem... ton thanks to @AtishAgrawal and also try to upvote my questions

Comment: @DroidLife Glad, it helped. It's okay. No need to upvote. Just mark this answer as accepted.